# Send image to server over sockets

Tags: python, image, sockets

I'm trying to send image to setver, but something goes wrong. I cannot open the recived file.

Server:

```
    with open("image.jpg", "wb") as fw:
        print("Receiving..")
        while True:
            data = c.recv(1024)
            image += data
            if data == b'BEGIN':
                continue
            elif data == b'ENDED':
                break
            else:
                fw.write(image)
        fw.close()
        print("Received..")
```

Client:

```
    with open('/home/pi/Desktop/image_to_send.jpg', 'rb') as fs: 
       self.soc.send(b'BEGIN')
       while True:
            data = fs.read(1024)
            self.soc.send(data)
            if not data:
                break
            self.soc.send(b'ENDED')
            fs.close()
```

Comment: you add `BEGIN` and `ENDED` to file `.jpg` because you do `image += data` before you check value in `data`

Comment: you have wrong indentions in client and you close it after first `send(data)`

Comment: you should open received file in text editr or better in hex editor to see what you get. It should help you see mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First mistake: you add `BEGIN` and `ENDED` to `image` and you save it. Besides if you will add `data` to `imag` and write it in every loop then you will save the same part of image in file many times.

```
with open("image.jpg", "wb") as fw:
    print("Receiving..")
    while True:
        data = c.recv(1024)
        if data == b'BEGIN':
            continue
        elif data == b'ENDED':
            break
        else:
            fw.write(data)
    fw.close()
    print("Received..")
```

Second mistake: you have wrong indentions in client and you run `send('ENDED')` after first `send(data)`

```
with open('/home/pi/Desktop/image_to_send.jpg', 'rb') as fs: 
   self.soc.send(b'BEGIN')
   while True:
        data = fs.read(1024)
        self.soc.send(data)
        if not data:
            break
   self.soc.send(b'ENDED')
   fs.close()
```

---

I would send it without `BEGIN` and `ENDED`. When client closes connection then server should receive zero `data` or `EOF` - so you could check `if not data:` in server and close file.